# Action Script : Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftbrace

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

From the Google search, I found so many faced this error but still I couldn't fix this issue in my code, SO had to create this new thread :|

I used sothink SWF quicker to edit a existing swf file ( [SWF file I used](http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/265/8/d/birthday_swf_by_zedrin-d5fjn8h.swf) )

I imported this swf file and when I tried to preview the swf file it produced these errors

ERROR: fromtext_15.as, Line 7: Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftbrace.
ERROR: BirthdayTitle_14.as, Line 7: Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftbrace.

```
package egobirthdaySWF_fla
{
    import flash.display.*;

    dynamic public class BirthdayTitle_14 extends MovieClip
    {

        public function BirthdayTitle_14()
        {
            addFrameScript(277, frame278);
            return;
        }// end function

        function frame278()
        {
            stop();
            return;
        }// end function
    }
}


package egobirthdaySWF_fla
{
    import flash.display.*;

    dynamic public class fromtext_15 extends MovieClip
    {

        public function fromtext_15()
        {
            addFrameScript(302, frame303);
            return;
        }// end function

        function frame303()
        {
            stop();
            return;
        }// end function

    }
}
```

can somebody help me to fix this (:

Comment: this is decompiled code btw. As far as you guys know stackoverflow is helping stealing somebody's work with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are missing the return type ...

```
public function Function(args ..):TYPE{


return variable_of_TYPE;
}
```

like `:void  :int  :boolean ....`

this is how [Functions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html) must be defined and used

And btw, I love your SWF xD

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, specifying return types for your functions and typing your variables are the two most common problems to "scan" for as you move back and forth between AS and JS.