# ActionScript Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftbrace

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I´m using SoThink SWH Quicker to edit existing file, all is working well, but i still gets
error: *Line 7: Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftbrace.* & I don´t know how to fix this issue, i was searching for it but i didn´t found nothing what works there, I hope you know how to help me, Thank you.

Source:

```
1: package 
2: {
3:    import flash.display.*;
4:
5:    dynamic public class env3Fg extends MovieClip
6:    {
7:        //Line 7: Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftbrace.
8:        public function env3Fg()
9:        {
10:            return;
11:        }// end function
12:
13:    }
14: }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332251/action-script-syntax-error-expecting-identifier-before-leftbrace

Comment: this is decompiled code btw. As far as we know stackoverflow is helping stealing somebody's work with this question.

Comment: Forget decompilers if you're struggling with this. It's a basic fix even for a first timer. Just do a tutorial!! If you want to know how to make a .AS class document and functions that that dont give problems, 10 minutes on Google search for tutorials you will learn more than all day in a decompiler. Also decompiled code aint fun for experts so it's not even trying to be best for a beginner.

Comment: Why `dynamic public class` instead of `public class`? Is that for your benefit or the decompiler's? Don't know? Close the decompiler & read the manual..